# Date Format issue STR_TO_DATE('18:11:52', '%H:%i:%s') Returns NULL

Tags: mysql, linux, database, database-administration

I am trying to change a string to time format but it seems some issue at my database configuration. because when I am trying following query it gives me null in return

```
mysql> select STR_TO_DATE('18:11:52', '%H:%i:%s');
+-------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE('18:11:52', '%H:%i:%s') |
+-------------------------------------+
| NULL                                |
+-------------------------------------+
mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                       |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1411 | Incorrect datetime value: '18:11:52' for function str_to_date |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I try same query in another Mysql Server it goes fine. There must be some configuration issue.
I appreciate if anyone can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange. I found that it works in MySQL 5.5, but not in 5.7.

Comment: Seems like a bug.

Comment: Just for reference, you're statement works for me on mysql 5.6. I do wonder if you've got something different in your configuration.  Is there any chance you can add the output from `show variables like "sql_mode";` I see that in the mysql documentation there is at least one gatcha based around sql_mode https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: It might also be worth doing a date format test just to see if something unexpected comes up, something like  `SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2007-10-04 22:23:00', '%H:%i:%s');`

Comment: what happens with these?
`SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE';
select STR_TO_DATE('18:11:52', '%H:%i:%s');`
and
`SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
select STR_TO_DATE('18:11:52', '%H:%i:%s');`

Comment: Yes. its also work for me.
    

`mysql> SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'; select STR_TO_DATE('18:11:52', '%H:%i:%s');
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    +-------------------------------------+
    | STR_TO_DATE('18:11:52', '%H:%i:%s') |
    +-------------------------------------+
    | 18:11:52                            |
    +-------------------------------------+`

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means you have the `NO_ZERO_DATE` or `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` SQL mode enabled, so MySQL will not allow you to convert a time string with an implicit date of `0000-00-00` to a datetime.

Since your input value is actually a time string (not a datetime) it might make more sense for you to use the `CONVERT()` function, like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT('18:11:52', TIME);
```

Comment: Yes I did @Barmar

Comment: @Barmar Thank you for let me know about this. I just did it now.